# Display the name of the column as data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If source table is:

```
City         1996-MAY  1996-june  1996-july 1996-aug  1996-sep  1996-okt
 -----------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
New Orleans         6          3         3         3         3         3    
Los Angeles         4          3         3         3         3         3
```

```
select city, 1996-MAY, 1996-june, 1996-july, 1996-aug, 1996-sep, 1996-okt
  from a
```

The requested result is:

```
City         People    Date
-----------  --------  --------
New Orleans         6  1996-MAY
Los Angeles         4  1996-MAY  
New Orleans         3  1996-june
Los Angeles         3  1996-june  
New Orleans         3  1996-july 
Los Angeles         3  1996-july 
....            ...        .....
```

How should I do it?

This is not only one column, it's a lot of columns up to 2003-MAY.

Comment: do you want Date in output too??

Comment: Can you amend your example to show desired results for more than one column then? Not clear if you are trying to unpivot or what.

Comment: Martin - I can show you some example.     
Fahim- Not the date

Comment: you need a pivot for this.... or a stupid years*12 tables union'ed :D

Comment: I am not expert on sql-server but i think you need unpivot. Row to column is pivot. Column to row is unpivot.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that the table structure is horrible with those per-month columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT  City, Date, People
FROM    T
        UNPIVOT 
        (   People 
            FOR Date IN ([1996-May], [1996-June], [1996-July])
        ) upvt
```

You could also do this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @SQL = ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM    SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE   OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('TableName')  
AND     Name != 'City'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT  City, Date, People
            FROM    T
                    UNPIVOT 
                    (   People 
                        FOR Date IN (' + STUFF(@SQL, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) upvt'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```